# IntelliJ 10.5.2 on Mac OS X Lion: Command-Option-L stops working

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, osx-lion

This is just plain weird.

For some reason, the accelerator Cmd-Opt-L (reformat code) no longer works inside IntelliJ 10.  This started with one of my projects and seems to have "spread".

Other accelerators work normally.  Reformat works if I use the menu to select it, or Cmd-Shift-A and choose it from the "Find action ..." popup dialog.

I've tried to see if some conflicting application is the cause. I'm using 1Password and it defines an accelerator for Cmd-Option-L, but I disabled that, restarted IntelliJ and still no dice.

A quit-and-restart doesn't help.

More oddness.  I pulled down the Code menu and typed Cmd-Opt-/ ... I can see the menu item flash and then my editor updates.  If I pull down the Code menu and type Cmd-Opt-L, there's no reaction (the menu line for Reformat Code does not flash, the menu stays up).  So ... one theory is that something elsewhere on my Mac is consuming the Cmd-Opt-L before it gets to IntelliJ?  If that's so, how would I track it down?

Answer (score 0):

Your theory is correct. As a workaround you can remap reformat code action to different shortcut in Settings | Keymap.

As for tracing the offending application, I'd try killing one by one and see when it starts working again.

Comment: I have killed off all my other apps; I even uninstalled Snap-Z-Pro just to be safe!  As I said, this is weird stuff!  I'll see what happens if I remap the action inside IntelliJ.

Comment: Remapped it to ctrl-alt-cmd-f and it works fine.  Still wierd! I'd like to know what's going on ...

Comment: Did you install any plug-ins or changed any keymap settings in IDEA? Try to start IDEA with the default settings after renaming its directories, see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181.

Comment: I don't think I've installed anything much, especially not recently. Mostly running with standard. I'll look into a couple of things (such as the Clojure plugin).

Comment: Somewhere along the line, this started working again; I don't know if it was an upgrade to IntelliJ 11 or something else.